# unable to get ng-watch to work in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Background**: The user inputs his city in the textbox, and then he is taken to a new page where the day's average temperature is shown, along with a general weather forecast(weather it is expected to rain,snow, etc..). I want the page to respond dynamically to the forecast, so if its expected to snow, it loads certain data. To that end, I have attached a model to the html element that is responsible for rendering the forecast. To get the forecast data in JSON, I am using OpenWeatherMap API (http://openweathermap.org/api)

**problem**: My angular app is not responsive to the weather forecast, and I am not sure why that's the case.

Here is the relevant angular code:

```
 $scope.forecast = '';

 $scope.isSnow = function() {

        var subString = 'snow';

        if (($scope.forecast).indexOf(subString) > -1) {
            return 'snow!';
        } else {
            return 'no snow';
        }              
    }
```

Here is the relevant html:

```
  <div class="panel-body">
                    Daytime temperature: {{convertToCelcius(W.temp.day)}} °C
                   general forecast: <div ng-model="forecast">{{W.weather[0].description}}</div> 
                    <div>{{isSnow()}}</div>
```

So even when the forecast says "light snow", the html is rendering "no snow". It is my understanding that ng-model works two ways, so whatever is changed in the html should be reflected in $scope.forecast, so why is that not happening?

Comment: Are you using a controller/app above that in the html?

Comment: Its working! Try this: http://plnkr.co/edit/7xgvalGLQs1xToP4pygP?p=preview